# OR logic filtering in AWSCLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Im trying to get a list of instances from AWS (using AWSCLI) with tag:env=stage OR tag:backup=true.

- i have 1 instance with tag backup=true
- i have 5 instance with tag env=stage
- i expect to get a list of 6 items

examples :

```
# returns no instances since its doing AND logic which is fine
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters "Name=tag:env,Values=stage" "Name=tag:backup,Values=true" \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,InstanceId][][]' | tr -d '[]"'

# returns only the last condition ( 1 instance )
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters "Name=tag:env,Values=stage" \
    --filters "Name=tag:backup,Values=true" \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,InstanceId][][]' | tr -d '[]"'

# returns only the last condition ( 5 instances )
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters "Name=tag:backup,Values=true" \
    --filters "Name=tag:env,Values=stage" \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,InstanceId][][]' | tr -d '[]"'
```

Comment: What about doing two separate API calls?

Comment: I experimented a bit and, while you can provide `filter` multiple by separating them with a space (`--filters "Name=tag:backup,Values=true" "Name=tag:env,Values=stage"`), they seem to perform an _AND_ rather than an _OR_. I recommend getting back _all_ results (no filter) and then filtering the result set yourself. This will be easier in a language like Python.